# Como configurar servidores espejos en ubuntu server 16.04?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

Tengo 3 servidores con el sistema Ubuntu Server 16.04 a los cuales les instale SQL Server 2017 Developer. Estoy intentando realizar una configuración de espejeo entre estos 3 servidores (principal, espejo y testigo) pero al momento de finalizar con la configuración e intentar iniciar el espejeo SQL me manda el error 1418.
Mi problema es que no se como solucionar el error en ubuntu.

Para realizar las configuraciones lo hago mediante SSMS 2014 que tengo instalado en una PC con Windows 7.

Espero puedan ayudarme...[image: Imagen de error de SQL Server]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Con respecto de tu pregunta, creo que el mensaje de error es bastante claro y no me queda claro que es lo que no sabes que hacer en ubuntu. Sospecho que si supieras resolver este problema en Windows, tu pregunta sería cómo abrir un puerto en ubuntu, así que no me queda claro realmente cual es tu pregunta.

Comment: para descartar un problema de credenciales fijate si este hilo te ayuda https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049634/1423096

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda....
Después de buscar a fondo en documentación oficial de Microsoft descubrí que no es posible realizar el espejeo en Ubuntu puesto que esta y muchas mas características aun no están disponibles para este sistema operativo.